# Backbone.js Undefined in Router initialize function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm getting an "undefined" in the initialize function. All I want to do is to fetch the collection data and on success use html() to put it in the DOM.

This is my Router:

```
var OverviewApp = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {"": "times_day", "weeks":"times_week"},

    initialize: function(){
        this.dayCollection = new DayCollection({});
        this.weekCollection = new WeekCollection({});

        this.dayTableView = new CollectionDayView({collection: this.dayCollection});
        this.weekTableView = new CollectionWeekView({collection: this.weekCollection});

        this.dayCollection.fetch({
            success: function(){
                this.dayTableView.render();    <--- HERE
                $("#times_day").html(this.dayTableView.el);
            }
        });
    },
```

Firebug says "this.dayTableView" is undefined. It is understandable cause it is not in the function context, then I tried doing:

```
this.dayCollection.fetch({
            success: function(this.dayTableView){
                this.dayTableView.render();
                $("#times_day").html(this.dayTableView.el);
            }
        });
```

But now the error is "SyntaxError: missing formal parameter". ... Not sure how to solve this, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What does your DayCollection definition look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

```
    this.dayCollection.fetch({
        success: function(){
            this.dayTableView.render();
            $("#times_day").html(this.dayTableView.el);
        }.bind(this)
    });
```

or

```
    var that = this;
    this.dayCollection.fetch({
        success: function(){
            that.dayTableView.render();
            $("#times_day").html(that.dayTableView.el);
        }
    });
```